# All the deleted files keeps getting added to System and not freeing up space on my Macbook

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, high-sierra

I deleted the macOS installer file and Xcode application but instead of freeing up my space it got added in this section with title System and its greyed out section so I am unable to access it. Is there any way I can free that space?

[image]

In the screenshot you can see System occupying 116.09 GB.

I am currently running macOS high sierra developer beta on Macbook pro mid-2015 15" model.

EDIT :

The Storage under system is now 194.15 GB, whatever I am deleting it is adding it to the system and is not freeing any space. Somebody Please Help Me :(

[image]

Also I tried using omnidisk but is only shows the space that is being used other than the system space I am not sure what else I could do now.

[image]

As you can see above it says 240 GB used but when I click on my Macintosh HD it only shows 141.3 GB.

Comment: Did you try to restart your Mac?

Comment: Yes I did that, several times, still no luck :(

Comment: You can try to check what files taking the most size with 3-rd party software like OmniDiskSweeper https://www.omnigroup.com/more

Comment: I tried OmniDiskSweeper but it only shows 141.3 GB Storage used. :( I am out of options :(

Comment: also that 116.09 GB has increased now to 141.95 GB :(

Comment: Are you permanently deleting things, or moving them to Trash?  If permanently, then can you give an example of which files got converted to System space usage?

Comment: I was trying to permanently delete things, and not only deleting it, even if i moved my files to external storage, it would allocats that space to system as well and so i decided to factory reset my laptop.

Comment: @AnkitJain you may run disk utility to check and repair your volume https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201639

Comment: I ran the disk utility and it showed no errors, but when i entered the recovery mode and than ran it, it gave me some errors, also i was unable to find any solutions to this issue so i decided to factory reset my laptop but I ran into issue there as well, posting a different question for that issue.